# How do I remove the chewing gum stuck in my shoe?

Tags: cleaning, shoes

There are times where I have stepped on chewing gum while walking down the streets. I have tried to scrape it off on the curb, but that only made it firm because of the ridges on my shoes. I tried to remove it with a stick but that's not effective.

I have came across chemicals like WD 40, but I'm not interested in spending money for these things. I heard freezing the chewing gum will help remove the gum, but I don't like the idea of putting my dirty shoe inside the freezer in any way.

How can I get the chewing off my shoe?

Comment: This reminds me of the [shoe bomb part](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q9wlRECdBo) from [Get Smart](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Get_Smart_(film))

Answer (score 8):

> I heard freezing the chewing gum will help to remove, but I don't like to put my dirty shoe inside the freezer in any way.

Then don't put the shoe in the freezer, rather apply ice directly to the gum. Ideally use a plastic wrap or similar to stop the gum getting wet as the ice melts.

Comment: You can also use wart freezing treatment (available in pharmacies, at least in the USA), "canned air" held upside down so the liquid sprays out, or (if you have some around) dry ice.  All freezing methods work by making the gum brittle due to the cold; once well chilled, it will chip right off.

Comment: Put shoe inside a ziplock bag and put that ziplock bag inside freezer to freeze the gum

Answer (score 4):

You could put your shoe into a plastic grocery bag, and put that in the freezer. Then it won't count as a 'dirty shoe'. Then, when the gum is stiff, pry it off. I use my pocketknife, but anything stiff and pointy should do fine. It may come off in more than one piece.

I have a big freezer, so I used a shoebox for this once, but a plastic bag would work fine.

Applying ice to the gum only works if you can make a lot of contact for a long time. Water will drip all over, so do it over an area you don't mind wiping up.

I've found that peanut butter does not work that well, but you do end up with peanut butter all over your shoe. The best method I know is to put it inside something and put that into the freezer (to keep the freezer clean).

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way to remove the chewing gum off your shoe is by dipping a piece of cloth into kerosene and use it to rub the gum until it looses it stickiness.

Answer (score 0):

Stick the shoe into the freezer.

The water on the chewing gum will freeze (I hope) and you can remove it easily.

I have never tried this, but you can try it.

Comment: This was mentioned in the question itself along with reason why it will not work for the OP

Comment: I ll prefer my food inside my freezer rather than dirty shoes!

Answer (score 0):

Look for a little bit of dirt or sand without rocks.

Step on the dirt and make sure the gum is full of dirt.

This will make the gum to be more easily removed with a stick, but a small amount of residues will be left behind.

If you are worried about that, just get some slippers and avoid using the shoes at home.

Answer (score 0):

A chewing/bubble gum is always a mess when it sticks to an object (shoe, cloth, etc)

My answer will add two ways after **freezing** and **ice cubes**:

**1. Freezer**
Put the shoe in a plastic bag. Wrap the bag tightly against the shoe and close the bag well. Put the shoe into the freezer for about one hour. When you take the shoe out of the bag, you will see that the gum is stuck to the bag.

**2. Ice cubes**
Put the shoe in a plastic bag with ice cubes. Make sure the ice cubes only touch the soles or the heels, or you may damage the shoe. Press the bag so that the ice cubes press against the gum. Hold it there for a while, so the ice cubes freeze the gum. When the gum is frozen, remove it with a knife.

**3. WD-40**

Spray the gum with WD-40 and wait one minute. The gum should come off with a paper towel

**4. Peanut butter**

Apply a thick layer of creamy peanut butter to the gum. Leave the peanut butter in place for about 10 minutes. Rub a wire brush over the area to remove the gum. The peanut butter will pull the gum off along with it. When it's gone, clean the sole of the shoe with water

I love peanut butter, and would consider last possible approach.

I have followed this [reference](http://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/household-hints-tips/cleaning-organizing/how-to-get-gum-off-shoes.htm)

Stay gum-free, stay clean